# I want to check if my id or class exists in a table | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, class

I have 2 tables, one with select option and one with results. When I choose one name from select, I show me some images from results. I do when I click specifically one name from select, change css styles. That do it but I want to do only if have id (div_new) or class (newA). Namely, I want to check if my id or class exists in one images from results to change my styles.
How can i do that???

With following code, it changes both images not one!

```
var playerAward = document.getElementById("my_select");
var playerAward2 = document.getElementById("my_select2");
var playerSelected = playerAward[playerAward.selectedIndex].value;
var playerSelected2 = playerAward2[playerAward2.selectedIndex].value;

if ((playerSelected == '.Athinodoros' && playerSelected2 == '.Dionisis' && $('#div_new').hasClass(".newA"))
|| (playerSelected == '.Dionisis' && playerSelected2 == '.Athinodoros' && $('#div_new').hasClass(".newA"))) {
      $('.award').css('box-shadow', 'inset 0 0 0 1.5px black');
      $('.award').css('background', 'rgb(255, 250, 240)');
      $('.award').css('background', 'rgba(255, 250, 240, 0.5)');
}

<DIV Class="column">
    <DIV ID="div_new" Class="award Athinodoros Dionisis newA">
        <P><IMG SRC="Team BanList\Ban\Dark Room of Nightmare.jpg"><BR>
        <LABEL Class="overlay">Dark Room of<BR>Nightmare</LABEL></P>
    </DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV Class="column">
    <DIV Class="award Athinodoros Dionisis">
        <P><IMG SRC="Team BanList\Ban\Moisture Creature.jpg"><BR>
        <LABEL Class="overlay"><BR>Moisture Creature</LABEL></P>
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: You question is not clear. However, if what you're asking is to check whether an element with a particular id exists, you can simply have: `var playerAward = document.getElementById("my_select");` and then check if it exists by going `if(playerAward != null && playerAward != undefined) { }`

Comment: i want check newA if exists. My selects are correct.

Comment: Then the code is: `if(whatever.classList.contains("newA"))) { }` with `var whatever = document.getElementById('div_new'');`

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: Both images change styles but i want only the image with id (div_new) and class (newA). What can add to if to do that.

Comment: You must check the correct div. So, check the div associated with `ID="div_new"` and use `classList` to check the class is within it. This function works fine, read more here [classlist](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)

Comment: The reason they're both changing styles is because you're telling the code that anything with the `award` class should change. Both divs have the `award` class, therefore they're changing styles.

Comment: If you ONLY want the `newA` class to ever change styles, in this declaration `$('.award').css('box-shadow', 'inset 0 0 0 1.5px black');` just change all `.award` to `.newA`

Comment: No it doing it again! and i change .award

Comment: Do you have any console errors? You have quite a bit of invalid HTML, so maybe run your code through this [HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options) as you might find that unexpected results are caused by invalid HTML.

Comment: it's work!!! Thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I do this after, but nothing.

```
var newAward = document.getElementById("div_new");

if ((playerSelected == '.Athinodoros' && playerSelected2 == '.Dionisis' && newAward.classList.contains("newA"))
|| (playerSelected == '.Dionisis' && playerSelected2 == '.Athinodoros' && newAward.classList.contains("newA"))) {
      awardColor = awardColorChange();
    } else if (playerSelected == "" && playerSelected2 == "") {
      awardColor = awardColorChange2();
    }
```